# D7-brane in Type IIB and axio-dilaton

Tags: string-theory, branes, axion

In the context of Type IIB string theory with one D7-brane we have the following situation. The axio-dilaton complex scalar is defined by $\tau:= C_0+i e^{-\phi}$ where $C_0$ is the axion and $\phi$ the dilaton. If we identify the 2-dimensional plane transverse to the D7-brane with $\mathbb{C}$ then $\tau = \tau(z,\bar{z}) $ must be holomorphic and is given in implicit form by the equation:
$$ j(\tau)= z^{-1} $$
where $j$ is the modular invariant Jacobi function. In the vicinity of $z=0$ (which is the location of the brane) we have the behaviour:
$$\tau \sim \frac{1}{2\pi i} \log (z)$$
from which we conclude that $\tau \to i \infty $ as $z \to 0$ and so the claim is made that near the D7-brane we have weak coupling.

My questions are the following:

1. Why does $\tau$ only depend on the coordinates of the transversal plane?
2. Can someone provide a derivation of the solution including the Jacobi function?
3. What do we mean when we say that "the region near the brane is weakly coupled"? The coupling of string theory $g_s$ is the vacuum expectation value of the field $e^{\phi}$ so does it make sense to talk about $e^{\phi}$ as a "coupling" that depends on spacetime coordinates? I mean, does this sentence have an actual physical meaning or is it just a schematic way of speaking?